# Trying to subscribe to a behavior subject in my user profile component but I keep getting initial null value

Tags: firebase, rxjs, observable, angular7, behaviorsubject

I have a user profile component that is trying to subscribe to a behavior subject in my user service. I set the initial value of the behavior subject to null. When a user signs up, I pass values to my user object within my signup component as well and then pass those same values to a method that saves them within my next subject.

Though when I subscribe within my ngOnIt on my user-profile component I only get my initial value back. Am I missing something here? From what I've read, I've checked to make sure I'm not providing multiple instances of my User Service and I've used value, getValue, and subscribe to get the value. All returning null.

```js
export class UserProfileComponent implements OnInit {

user: User;

  ngOnInit() {
// My problem.
    this.user = this.userService.getSavedUser().getValue();
    console.log(this.user);
  }

}
```

```js
// object

export class User {
    firstName: string;
    lastName: string;
    email: string;
    mobile: string;
    uid: string;
    termsOfAgreement: boolean;

    constructor(
        email: string,
        mobile: string,
        firstName: string,
        lastName: string,
        uid: string,
        termsOfAgreement: boolean
    ) {
        this.email = email;
        this.mobile = mobile;
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.uid = uid;
        this.termsOfAgreement = false;

    }
}
```

```js
signup.component.ts

onSignup(signupFormData) {
        return this.afAuth.auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(signupFormData.value.email, signupFormData.value.password)
            .then(userInfo => {
                // Pass in user info into to user object. 
                const user: User = new User(signupFormData.value.email,
                    signupFormData.value.mobile, signupFormData.value.firstName,
                    signupFormData.value.lastName,
                    userInfo.user.uid, false);
                this.writeNewUser(user);

            }).catch((error) => {
                this.showError = true;
                this.errorMessage = error.message;
            })
    }

    private writeNewUser(user: User): void {
        this.userService.addUser(user);
    }
```

```js
// user.service.ts

export class UserService {

  private subject: BehaviorSubject<User> = new BehaviorSubject(null);


public addUser(user: User): void {
    this.db
      .collection("users")
      .doc(user.uid)
      .set(Object.assign({}, user));
    this.saveUser(user);
  }

  public saveUser(user: User) {
    this.subject.next(user);
  }

  public getSavedUser(): BehaviorSubject<User> {
    return this.subject;
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi @eye4eneye, try to remove redundant code from your snippets like imports or part of code not strictly related to your issue. It would be so much easier to find solution

Comment: @MarekSzkudelski Hello Marek! I have removed some code and added my problem to the top. Does this help?

Answer (score 1):

As you've written problem is in your component. You didn't subscribe to Subject but tried to get value in time of executing ngOnInit method.

```js
export class UserProfileComponent implements OnInit {
  user: User;

  ngOnInit() {
    this.userService.getSavedUser().subscribe(
      (value) => {
        this.user = value;
        console.log(this.user);
      }
    );
  }

}
```

Now you will receive every value emitted by Subject, starting from moment you subscribed to it (and last emitted)

**Side note:**

Best practice is to returning Subject casted to Observable (in your UserService). When you return Subject someone could use next method and emit some value. If you want only service to emit new values you have to return `this.subject.asObservable()` (and change typings)

**Side note 2:**

Remember to unsubscribe Subject on component's destroy - ngOnDestroy method

Comment: I’ve tried this notation as well. I get an error returned to the console that says “Type ‘Subscription’ is missing the following properties from type Users: firstName, lastName, email, mobile, and 2 more.

Comment: You probably tried to assign value returned by subscribe to user property? You need to assign value inside callback

Comment: I wrote it as you have it in your reply. this.user = this.userService.getSavedUser().subscribe((value) => { this.user = value; console.log(this.user); }); }

Comment: Yes, that was my mistake, but I corrected it quickly. Now is it working for you?

Comment: Sadly no. Still returning null. I've scanned a lot of questions like mine and they are all writing it the same way. I'm having no luck. Console just reads null. I've read that I could use ReplaySubject(1) or skip operator but that also didn't work. Maybe ngOnInit is trying to emit before the value is set in saveUser method?

Comment: BehaviorSubject should emit last value to every subscribe, no matter when subscription is made. Ensure that you perform action that trigger Subject to emit new value. If it will not work, then I suggest you to reproduce issue in stackblitz.com and paste link into your question

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/210715/discussion-between-marek-szkudelski-and-eye4eneye).